# How to calcuate the inner product

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra

How would I calculate the inner product of $|+\rangle|+\rangle$ and $\alpha|00\rangle+\beta|11\rangle$?

I am very new to quantum computing, but I believe for the second problem it would be the probability added? And the probability of α|00⟩  is 1/2 while the probability of β|11⟩ is 0? Let me know if I am way off on this. Thinking along the same lines, I need to find the probability of $|+\rangle|+\rangle$ I believe, but I just cannot find how to do this correctly. Again, I am just learning this subject so sorry if this sounds like rubbish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

First note that: $|+\rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$

Second note that: $|u v \rangle = |u\rangle \otimes |v\rangle$

Third note that:  $\langle u_1 \otimes u_2 | v_1 \otimes v_2 \rangle =  \langle u_1|v_1\rangle \cdot \langle u_2|v_2\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

I think some clarification on what you're trying to do here would be helpful. Are you trying to find out the inner product *between* $|+\rangle |+\rangle$ and  $\alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle$? I'm a bit unclear what you mean when you say "I need to find the probability of $|+⟩|+⟩$".

For some state $|\psi\rangle$ expressed in the computational basis $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$, one is usually interested in determining the probability of a certain *outcome*. So for example, if we have
$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle,
$$
we can ask, "what is the probability $P_0$ of the outcome $|0\rangle$ and the probability $P_1$ of outcome $|1\rangle$?" These are calculated as
$$
\begin{split}
P_0 = |\langle 0|\psi\rangle|^2 = |\langle0|\left( \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \right)|^2 = |\alpha \langle0|0\rangle + \beta\langle 0|1\rangle|^2 = |\alpha|^2\\
P_1 = |\langle 1|\psi\rangle|^2 = |\langle1|\left( \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \right)|^2 = |\alpha \langle1|0\rangle + \beta\langle 1|1\rangle|^2 = |\beta|^2
\end{split}
$$
With this in mind, recognize that $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$, and $|+\rangle|+\rangle = |+\rangle \otimes |+\rangle = |++\rangle$. Now if you were trying to determine the inner product between $|++\rangle$ and $\alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle$, we would have
$$
\langle++|(\alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle) = \alpha\langle++|00\rangle + \beta\langle++|11\rangle.
$$
Hope this helps! If you need more clarification, I'd highly recommend an introductory QM textbook like Townsend, or QC and QI by Nielsen and Chuang. Or just add follow-up comments!